# Basis and vectors span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector-subspace of $R^4$ and the span of $V$ is given by $w_1 = {(1,1,0,0), w_2 = (1,0,2,0),w_3 = (2,1,2,0),w_4 = (0,0,0,1),w_5=(0,1,-2,1)}$.

First i tried to find out which vector are linearly independent or dependent:

$w_3$ is linear combination of $w_1$ and $w_2$.

$w_5$ is linear combination of $w_1,w_2,w_4$. So i have three independent vectors ($w_1,w_2,w_4$).

My book says that this is a basis for $V$ which is a subspace of $R^4$ and i think this is not true because we can't represent each vector in $R^4$ with only these three vectors or isn't equivalent if i say that i have two vectors 
 $\begin{bmatrix}
     1\\
     1\\
     0
  \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
     0\\
     0\\
     1
  \end{bmatrix}$ and this is the basis of $R^3$ which i think is not true because we can represent $z = 0$ or $x,y = 0$ but we can't represent a vector $x = 1 , y = 0 , z  = 0/1$ by making a linear combination.  So my question is do these three vector create a basis for $R^4$?

Comment: Your book said basis for subespace V, not basis for $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Any number of linearly independent vectors are basis for some subespace with dimension equal the number of vector in the basis.

Comment: You state that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and in this case not $\mathbb{R}^4$ itself.

Comment: It is a good question and you already received two good remarks! Subspace.....